# Do any countries besides the USA accept Basic Med?

Tags: regulations, international, basicmed

Are other countries accepting Basic Med for flights through their airspace, for example the European Union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I've made this a community wiki answer so that others can add new information if/when things change.)

These countries allow US pilots to fly with BasicMed:

- [The Bahamas](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2017/may/18/bahamas-welcomes-basicmed-pilots)
- [Mexico](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2019/october/14/mexico-welcomes-pilots-flying-under-basicmed) (from 10 Dec 2019)

Comment: I marked this as the answer but would you please share where or how you found this?

Comment: @jwzumwalt It was in an AOPA email I got some time ago, and there's a bit of discussion on it in their forums too. AOPA's trying to persuade Canada and Mexico too, but it isn't easy. BasicMed isn't ICAO-compliant so each country has to decide individually to accept it or not, and most of them don't see it as a priority. They also don't want to allow foreigners to fly in their airspace with a 'lesser' medical than their own citizens require. And in the case of Canada, the US doesn't accept their class 4 medical here, so why should they accept BasicMed there? Politics, in other words :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### [According to AOPA](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/pilots/medical/basicmed):

> The following countries authorize BasicMed privileges:
>
> - United States
> - Mexico
> - The Bahamas
> - The Dominican Republic
> - Puerto Rico
> - U.S. Virgin Islands
> - American Samoa
> - Northern Mariana Islands
> - Micronesia
> - Guam
> - Marshall Islands
> - Palau.

*[Edited to abbreviate country names and put it in list format.]*

Comment: Puerto Rico, US Virgin Islands, American Samoa, Northern Mariana Islands, and Guam are all part of the US.

Comment: Indeed they are.  I guess AOPA mentioned them in case there was any doubt as to the legality in U.S. territories.